# Font size changes after reload

Tags: javascript, css

[image]

After I click on A+ or A- it works perfectly, but the issue is after loading the page or cliking on some link on the page it goes back to normal.

I need it to maintain the size even after cliking on some link.

thank you for helping.

Here s the code:

```js
function increaseFont() {

  var currentFontSizeH1 = $('h1').css('font-size'); //36

  var currentFontSizeNumH1 = parseFloat(currentFontSizeH1, 5);

  var currentFontSizeNumH1 = currentFontSizeNumH1 + 1.5;

  $('h1').css('font-size', currentFontSizeNumH1);

  var deccurrentFontSize = $('body').css('font-size'); //14
  var deccurrentFontSizeNum = parseFloat(deccurrentFontSize, 10);
  var decnewFontSize = deccurrentFontSizeNum * 1.2;
  $('body').css('font-size', decnewFontSize);
  $('body').css('font-size', decnewFontSize);
  $('p').css('font-size', decnewFontSize);
  $('span').css('font-size', decnewFontSize);
  $('li').css('font-size', decnewFontSize);
  $('h2').css('font-size', decnewFontSize);

  $('a').css('font-size', decnewFontSize);

  return false;
}

function decreaseFont() {

  var currentFontSizeH1 = $('h1').css('font-size');

  var currentFontSizeNumH1 = parseFloat(currentFontSizeH1, 5);

  var currentFontSizeNumH1 = currentFontSizeNumH1 - 1.5;

  $('h1').css('font-size', currentFontSizeNumH1);

  var deccurrentFontSize = $('body').css('font-size');
  var deccurrentFontSizeNum = parseFloat(deccurrentFontSize, 10);
  var decnewFontSize = deccurrentFontSizeNum / 1.2;
  $('body').css('font-size', decnewFontSize);
  $('p').css('font-size', decnewFontSize);
  $('span').css('font-size', decnewFontSize);
  $('li').css('font-size', decnewFontSize);
  $('h2').css('font-size', decnewFontSize);

  $('a').css('font-size', decnewFontSize);

  return false;
}
```

```css
h1 {
  font-size: 36px;
  line-height: 42px;
  color: #007ea6;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 21px;
  color: #333333;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
.....
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div title="{" Increase the text size "|i18n( 'design/siteinstitutionnel/page_header_changerCSS' )}" style="width: 6px;" class="span1"><a href="#" style="text-decoration:none;font-size: 17px; box-shadow: 0 3px 0 #aaa,0px 0 0 #888,0px 3px 0 #666;" onClick="increaseFont();" alt="Aggrandir la taille du texte">A+</a>
</div>
<div title="{" Decrease the text size "|i18n( 'design/siteinstitutionnel/page_header_changerCSS' )}" style="width: 21px;" class="span1"><a href="#" style="text-decoration:none;font-size: 17px; box-shadow: 0 3px 0 #aaa,0px 0 0 #888,0px 3px 0 #666;" onClick="decreaseFont();" alt="Reduire la taille du texte">A-</a> 
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please post a clearer code? That one look like some esolang answers on the codegolf SE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could save the size in a variable in Window.sessionStorage.

```
// Save data to sessionStorage
sessionStorage.setItem('fontSize', value);

// Get saved data from sessionStorage
var size = sessionStorage.getItem('fontSize');
```

Data stored in sessionStorage gets cleared when the page session ends. A page session lasts for as long as the browser is open and survives over page reloads and restores. Opening a page in a new tab or window will cause a new session to be initiated.

Comment: Thank you. may I ask the diffrence between LocalStorage and sessionStorage

Comment: The only difference is that, while data stored in localStorage has no expiration time, data stored in sessionStorage gets cleared when the browsing session ends—that is, when the browser is closed.

Answer (score 3):

Localstorage would also be an option, but not supported by older browsers:

```
if(typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
    // Set the value
    localStorage.setItem("fontSize", fontSize);

    // Get the value
    var fontSize = localStorage.getItem("fontSize");
} else {
    // Sorry! No Web Storage support..
}
```

Alternatively you could use Cookies.

Answer (score 2):

If you want it to remain, you have to save it. In order to achieve that, you can use LocalStorage like

```
localStorage.setItem("fontSize", yourFontSize);
```

you can load the value in your $( document ).ready() like this

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var fontSize = localStorage.getItem("fontSize");
}
```